# Sequelize with NodeJS can't join tables with limit

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement a simple query that should look like this:

```
select * from property join entity_area on property.id=entity_area.entity_id and entity_area.area_id=1 where property.price>300000 limit 12
```

Pretty straightforward: I want to get the joined result and then to limit to 12.

In Sequelize i'm using the following function:

```
return models.property.findAll(
{
    where: ["price>=?", 300000],
    include: [
    {
        model:models.entity_area,
        where: { area_id:1 }
    }
    ],
    limit:12
})
```

But this code generates the following sql:

```
select property.*, entity_area.* from (select * from property where property.price>300000 limit 12) join entity_area on property.id=entity_area.entity_id and entity_area.area_id=1
```

Which has totally different logic from what i'm trying to do because in the generated sql it first gets any 12 results and then tries to join with entity_area, and of course the random 12 results don't necessarily match the entity_area, so i'm getting no results back.

Please suggest me a proper way of doing it. The property table is very massive, and i have to use the "limit" rather than getting all the results and slicing them in javascript. Also i wouldn't like to start using raw queries.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually I found a solution myself. I think this is a bug in sequelize framework.
In the node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialect/abstract/query_generator.js there is a "selectQuery" function which has the following line:

```
subQuery = limit && (options.hasIncludeWhere || options.hasIncludeRequired || options.hasMultiAssociation) && options.subQuery !== false
```

First of all there is an option subQuery that could be passed as false to remove the subquery generation. Sequelize documentation does not have a word about it. But moreover if you pass subQuery:false in the findAll object it's not going to work because for some reason it's getting as underfined to the selectQuery function. 
I tried something like:

```
return models.property.findAll(
{
    where: ["price>=?", 300000],
    include: [
    {
        model:models.entity_area,
        where: { area_id:1 }
    }
    ],
    limit:12,
    subQuery:false
})
```

and still got options.subQuery=undefined.

So i had to change the function in query_generator.js to be something like:

```
subQuery = limit && (options.hasIncludeWhere || options.hasIncludeRequired || options.hasMultiAssociation) && options.subQuery !== false && options.doSubQuery===true
```

So now by default it's not doing this ugly subquery unless i specify explicitely doSubQuery:true. And finally i got the proper query without subquery with limit.

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js#L876

Code looks a bit different these days so `options.subQuery = false` should simply work.

Comment: @MickHansen this solved my problem too, but I'm a bit concerned because this isn't in Sequelize's documentation. Is it safe to rely on that?

Comment: They fixed this problem in current version (@6.6.5). You need to use just `subquery: false` in options

Answer (score 10):

```
models.property.findAll(
{
    where: [...],
    include: [{...}],
    limit:12
},
{
    subQuery:false
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the right answar. You saved me lot of work

Comment: One issue with this solution: if any of the associated models have a one-to-many relationship with the base model, then less results will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem recently using sequelize 4.28.6, this is what worked for me

```
 User.findAll(
{
  where: {
    $Tasks$: null,
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: Task,
      // required: false,
    },
  ],
  limit: 3,
  subQuery: false,
})
```

@yuriscom answer still works but, i didnt want to edit the sequelize codebase since the issue has been fixed and adding `subQuery: false,` works

Comment: i have used subQuery: false but i think limit not working properly in my calse

Comment: It did work. but can someone pls explain why subQuery:false works ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution will behave as desired. If no subquery is used, then the limit effectively limits both users and tasks.  Eg if the first user in the result set has three tasks, then only that user will be returned.  And if a user has more than three tasks, then only three of his tasks will be included, and of course, no other users.

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this problem in current version of sequelize (@6.6.5). You need to use just `subquery: false` in options