# Nodejs heap out of memory during findOne Sequelize method with eager loading

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, heap-memory, node-mysql

My NodeJS application currently uses a Sequelize object for working across multiple stages. This object is the result of a Model.findOne operation, which includes several other models, similar to a left join with multiple tables in plain SQL.

```
transaction  = await Transaction.findOne({
            where: {
                id: transaction.id
            },
            include: transactionIncludes //this includes other models such as client, orderDetail, orderLog, etc
        })
    }
    return transaction
```

Sometimes, my application gets to mount this transaction object fine.
However, when I do try to scale it, I often get these OOM errors such as:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[736:0x60632a0]    72273 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2036.3 (2045.7) -> 2036.2 (2045.7) MB, 13.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.1 ms in 4 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 184 ms) (average mu = 0.943, current mu = 0.951) final[736:0x60632a0]    72342 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2041.9 (2051.4) -> 2041.9 (2051.4) MB, 10.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.5 ms in 4 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 64 ms) (average mu = 0.931, current mu = 0.833) finali

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb2c2b0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa4025c node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xd1d11e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xd1d497 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xed68f5  [node]
 6: 0xee7d3d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: 0xee8bf7 v8::internal::Heap::FinalizeIncrementalMarkingIfComplete(v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason) [node]
 8: 0xeec6b0 v8::internal::IncrementalMarkingJob::Task::RunInternal() [node]
 9: 0xddae0b non-virtual thunk to v8::internal::CancelableTask::Run() [node]
10: 0xb9a7f4 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::RunForegroundTask(std::unique_ptr<v8::Task, std::default_delete<v8::Task> >) [node]
11: 0xb9c669 node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [node]
12: 0x159d8a6  [node]
13: 0x15afe14  [node]
14: 0x159e1f8 uv_run [node]
15: 0xa65fe5 node::SpinEventLoop(node::Environment*) [node]
16: 0xb6ed86 node::NodeMainInstance::Run(node::EnvSerializeInfo const*) [node]
17: 0xaef83a node::Start(int, char**) [node]
18: 0x7f8cda3cb09b __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
19: 0xa62f6c  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The dumped core sits at around 2 gigs of memory.
I'd like to solve this without increasing RAM.

Edit: someone has asked me to show includes with model associations, here they are:

```
[redacted]
```

Comment: show `transactionIncludes` and also how all models are associated with each other.

Comment: hello, I have updated my question to include model associations. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You showed `emissaoIncludes` instead of `transactionIncludes`

Comment: I forgot to change const name. This is the correct object, sorry.

Comment: I don't see `VooIncludes` that is used in `transactionIncludes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one `hasMany` associations included in a Sequelize query (on the same level or on the nested level) then you need to indicate `separate: true` for all of them so Sequelize will perform all such included queries separately to avoid multiplying records:

```js
export const transactionIncludes = [
    {model: CartaoPagamentos, as: 'cartaopagamento', type: 'hasOne', foreignKey: 'transaction_id'},
    {model: Cliente, as: 'cliente', type: 'belongsTo', foreignKey: 'cliente_id'},
    {model: Fila, as: 'fila', type: 'hasOne', foreignKey: 'transaction_id'},
    {model: Voo, as: 'voo', type: 'hasMany', foreignKey: 'transaction_id', include: VooIncludes, separate: true }, 
    {model: Passageiros, as: 'passageiro', type: 'hasMany', foreignKey: 'transaction_id', separate: true },
    {model: Cartaomilhas, as: 'cartaomilha', type: 'hasOne', foreignKey: 'transaction_id'},
    {model: Robot, as: 'robot', type: 'belongsTo', foreignKey: 'robo_id'},
];
```

Also please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763084/1376618) (the part about `hasMany` to understand better what's going on under the hood when you indicate more than one `hasMany` in Sequelize queries without the `separate: true` option.