How to retrieve user data with associated transaction and payment records, including customer information, using Sequelize in Node.js?
I'm trying to retrieve specific user detail along with their transaction and payment, so basically there are four table User, Customers, Transaction and Payment
User has many Customers and Customers has many Transactions and Payments
Here is the query
const user = await User.findByPk(userId, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Customer,
      include: [
        { model: Transaction, include: Customer },
        { model: Payment, include: Customer }
      ]
    },
    { model: Expense }
  ]
});

the above query worked but I don't want customer array to be top level object, Instead I want to show Transactions and Payments array object directly in top level object where each array object has their associated customer
currently json object is appearing up like this
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  Customers: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Customer A',
        email: 'customer@example.com'
        Transaction: [],
        Payment: []
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Customer B',
        email: 'customer@example.com'
        Transaction: [],
        Payment: []
      }
      ]
      }

The desired data structure for the retrieved user object should look like this:
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  Transactions: [
    {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 10,
      Customer: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Customer A',
        email: 'customer@example.com'
      }
    },
    // Other milk objects
  ],
  Payments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      amount: 100,
      Customer: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Customer B',
        email: 'another@example.com'
      }
    },
    // Other payment objects
  ],
  Expenses: []
}


It;s much easier to do so by two queries against the models Transaction and Payment separately and combine the results in one object

That's what I'm thinking to do but I'm wondering if it is an efficient way to do it, because I would have to run two queries compared to doing it in one query @Anatoly

If it would be one query - under the hood in the SQL query there will be multiplication of payments and transactions records, see my explanation in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763084/1376618
