# Sequelize PG: select with join, order, limit

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize 3.30.0 with Postgres. This is the query I want to perform:

```
SELECT works.title, artists.name, artists.relevance
FROM works
JOIN artist_works ON works.work_id = artist_works.work_id
JOIN artists ON artists.artist_id = artist_works.artist_id
WHERE artists.label LIKE '%mozart%'
ORDER BY artists.relevance DESC
LIMIT 50
```

It is very simple and works like a charm if I do it directly on the db. However, trying to do the same with Sequelize doesn't appear to work (no results). This is how the `findAll` options look like:

```
Work.findAll({
   attributes : ['title'],
   include : [{
      attributes : [ 'name' ],
      model : Artist,
      where : { label : { $like : '%mozart%' } },
   }],
  limit : 50
})
```

The Sequelize-generated query is very convoluted:

```
SELECT "works".*, "artists"."artist_id" AS "artists.artistId", "artists"."name" AS "artists.name", "artists.artist_works"."artist_work_id" AS "artists.artist_works.artistWorkId", "artists.artist_works"."artist_id" AS "artists.artist_works.artistId", "artists.artist_works"."work_id" AS "artists.artist_works.workId", "artists.artist_works"."type" AS "artists.artist_works.type", "artists.artist_works"."artist_id" AS "artists.artist_works.artist_id", "artists.artist_works"."work_id" AS "artists.artist_works.work_id" 
FROM (
    SELECT "works"."work_id" AS "workId", "works"."title" 
    FROM "works" AS "works" 
    WHERE ( 
        SELECT "artist_works"."artist_work_id" 
        FROM "artist_works" AS "artist_works" 
        INNER JOIN "artists" AS "artist" ON "artist_works"."artist_id" = "artist"."artist_id" 
        WHERE ("works"."work_id" = "artist_works"."work_id") LIMIT 1 
    ) IS NOT NULL 
    LIMIT 50) AS "works" 
INNER JOIN (
   "artist_works" AS "artists.artist_works" 
      INNER JOIN "artists" AS "artists" ON "artists"."artist_id" = "artists.artist_works"."artist_id"
      ) ON "works"."workId" = "artists.artist_works"."work_id" AND "artists"."label" LIKE '%-mozart-%';
```

Please note that the query works if no limit is set. 
Additionally, when I try to also add an `order` option, the query freezes.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists related question [Sequelize with NodeJS can't join tables with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021965/sequelize-with-nodejs-cant-join-tables-with-limit), and the solution seems to be add `subQuery: false` to the `options` object in `findAll` method. It prevents creating this subquery you relate to.

I created identical association and added the `subQuery: false` and the subquery is not generated, as well as `LIMIT` and `ORDER` seem to work. However, I suggest taking a look on the source code of `selectQuery` from `node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js` if you really want to use the `subQuery` option because it is not mentioned in the documentation, so I do not guarantee it will work